# How can I unittest get_context_data() of a ListView in Django?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-class-based-views

I tried to write a unittest for a ListView in Django 3.0.5. I need to check the data included in the context. The Application is running for this view, so error in implementation is not likely. But what did I missed when setting up my test?

Here parts of my source:

**urls.py:**

```
app_name = 'gene'
urlpatterns = [
    path('persons/', views.PersonList.as_view(), name='person-list'),
    ...
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from gene.models import Person

class PersonList(ListView):
    model = Person

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PersonList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs) # this is line 11
        ...
        return context
```

**tests.py:**

```
from django.test import TestCase, RequestFactory
from django.urls import reverse

from gene.models import Person
from gene.views import PersonList

class PersonListTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        person1 = Person.objects.create(name="Person 1")
        person2 = Person.objects.create(name="Person 2")

    def test_context(self):
        request = RequestFactory().get(reverse('gene:person-list'))
        view = PersonList()
        view.setup(request)

        context = view.get_context_data() # this is line 20, Error here
        self.assertIn('environment', context)
```

I followed the guides from official documentation.

But when I run this test I get following on console:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/macbarfuss/PycharmProjects/Genealogy/gene/tests.py", line 20, in test_context
    context = view.get_context_data()
  File "/home/macbarfuss/PycharmProjects/Genealogy/gene/views.py", line 11, in get_context_data
    context = super(PersonList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
  File "/home/macbarfuss/PycharmProjects/Genealogy/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py", line 115, in get_context_data
    queryset = object_list if object_list is not None else self.object_list
AttributeError: 'PersonList' object has no attribute 'object_list'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django has a [**`Client`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#the-test-client) that allows you to inspect the `context`. Note that normally the context is *not* exported in the HTTP response, but it is patched here to allow that for testing:

```
import unittest
from django.test import Client

class SimpleTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        person1 = Person.objects.create(name="Person 1")
        person2 = Person.objects.create(name="Person 2")

    def test_details(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('gene:person-list'))
        self.assertIn('environment', response.context)
```

So the `response` has a [**`.context`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Response.context).

I advise to use the `Client` since class-based views are quite sophisticated, the flow can be "decyphered", but it requires some skill, by using a simple `.dispatch()`, etc. you only retrieve a `HttpResponse` without a `.context`, so it is probably better to use the tooling Django offers for this task.

Comment: normally i would consider a test utilizing a client not as unittest but integrationtest. This is because with Spring running a test with a client requires to start the hole spring context and this is much more slow than just invoking one method I want to test.

Is using the testclient from django efficient enough to consider it a fast uniitest?

Comment: @MacBarfuss: but the problem is that the `get_context_data` is not a "standalone" method. It is part of a "workflow". It expects that previous items did their job properly, for example `.setup()` to set a `request` object, sometimes `.object` is set by `get` and `post`.

Comment: I changed my test now and it needed 21 ms to run ... fast enough to be called a unittest. So this is for all the other Java developers gambling around with django: dont be afraid of running tests with a client. @Willem: thanks for your incredible fast answers.